# SQL "=" doesn't work on string while "LIKE" does.

Tags: sql

I am doing a simple data pull on a table with the below "WHERE" condition

```
SELECT * FROM table1
WHERE name = 'Amy' OR name = 'John'
```

There are no "johns" in the existing table currently so I expect the result to return only data with "Amy" (Amy is spelled the exact way in the DB). However, result did not return anything. However, when I enter the query as:

```
SELECT * FROM table1
WHERE name LIKE 'Amy' OR name LIKE 'John'
```

That returns my result as expected with only Amy's data in there. I understand the difference between '=' and 'LIKE', but why wouldn't using '=' in the first case return any results?

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: What database and DB version are you using?

Comment: You might be facing a collation or case-sensitivity issue.  Also, trailing spaces can be an issue.

Comment: Like Gordon says, there could be a trailing space or a case-sensitivity issue. '=' looks for an EXACT match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For pretty much any SQL compliant RDMS the first query works.  **Of course that assumes there is actually a record with the name being exactly 'Amy'.**  Not 'Amy ' or 'amy'.  LIKE is case insensitive so it will work even if you are imprecise.

Here is an example of the query working against a sample database.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c11c4/2)

**MS SQL Server 2014 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE table1
(
  name varchar(256)
);

INSERT INTO table1
VALUES
('Amy'),
('Bob'),
('Charles'),
('Doug'),
('Eve');
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT * FROM table1
WHERE name = 'Amy' OR name = 'John'
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c11c4/2/0)**:

```
| name | 
|------| 
|  Amy |
```

Answer (score 0):

That is probably because of the trailing space or some collation issue or case sensitivity issue. The [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx) for T-SQL says:

> When you perform string comparisons by using LIKE, all characters in
>   the pattern string are significant. This includes leading or trailing
>   spaces.

The same is valid for other SQL languages as well. I have just quoted it from T-SQL.

The [SQL Standard § 8.2](http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt) describes how `=` compares strings:

> The comparison of two character strings is determined as follows:
>
> a) If the length in characters of X is not equal to the length
>   in characters of Y, then the shorter string is effectively
>   replaced, for the purposes of comparison, with a copy of
>   itself that has been extended to the length of the longer
>   string by concatenation on the right of one or more pad 
>   characters, where the pad character is chosen based on CS. If
>   CS has the NO PAD attribute, then the pad character is an
>   implementation-dependent character different from any 
>   character in the character set of X and Y that collates less
>   than any string under CS. Otherwise, the pad character is a
>   .
>
> b) The result of the comparison of X and Y is given by the 
>   collating sequence CS.
>
> c) Depending on the collating sequence, two strings may 
>   compare as equal even if they are of different lengths or 
>   contain different sequences of characters. When the operations
>   MAX, MIN, DISTINCT, references to a grouping column, and the
>   UNION, EXCEPT, and INTERSECT operators refer to character
>   strings, the specific value selected by these operations from
>   a set of such equal values is implementation-dependent.

The [SQL Standard § 8.5](http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt) describes how `LIKE` compares strings:

> The <predicate>
>
> `M LIKE P`
>
> is true if there exists a partitioning of M into substrings
>   such that:
>
> i) A substring of M is a sequence of 0 or more contiguous
>   <character representation>s of M and each <character 
>   representation> of M is part of exactly one substring.
>
> ii) If the i-th substring specifier of P is an arbitrary 
>   character specifier, the i-th substring of M is any single
>   <character representation>.
>
> iii) If the i-th substring specifier of P is an arbitrary string
>   specifier, then the i-th substring of M is any sequence of
>   0 or more <character representation>s.
>
> iv) If the i-th substring specifier of P is neither an 
>   arbitrary character specifier nor an arbitrary string specifier, 
>   then the i-th substring of M is equal to that substring 
>   specifier according to the collating sequence of
>   the <like predicate>, without the appending of <space>
>   characters to M, and has the same length as that substring
>   specifier.
>
> v) The number of substrings of M is equal to the number of
>   substring specifiers of P.